# How to set #FF0B3663 to GradientStop Color

Tags: .net, wpf, gradientstop

Right now I am doing;

```
           var backGradient2 = new GradientStop();
           backGradient1.Offset = 0.5;
           backGradient1.Color = Colors.Yellow;
```

but I need to pass string like #FF0B3663

any idea?

thanks

Comment: **Solution:** use proper XAML to define the UI in XAML-based technologies, as opposed to a winforms-like procedural approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **`ColorConverter's`** method **`ConvertFromString`** to convert hex string value to actual color value:

```
backGradient1.Color = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FF0B3663");
```